# Magento admin panel not working on live server

Tags: php, magento

I am working on an eCommerce website using 'Magento'. It is working fine on my local server but when I upload this project onto the live server, its front-end is working fine but while logged in the admin panel show the following error.

[image]

I have already used the solution provided on Stackoverflow and other websites, But still have no success.

Comment: try this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13228/magento-error-currency-usd-not-found

Comment: use this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513229/cant-solve-currency-usd-not-found-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513229/cant-solve-currency-usd-not-found-error)

Comment: Well I have already used these links. :(